# Use a QtObject file for styles in QML

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to have a file like the following using QtObject with properties, where we have global styles and then access it on another QML files?

Globals.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
    id:objectCustom
    property int charWidth: 11
property var text: QtObject {
    property bool bold: true
    property int pointSize: 12
    property int languageSize: 14
    property color textColor: "#ffffff"
    property color textColor_top: "#26e400"
    property color textColor2: "#A9A9A9"

    property color textColor_misc: "#afbcfe" // "#0000ff"
    property color textColor_tmr: "#b4fde5" // "#008B8B"
    property color textColor_glb: "#feb5ed" //"#4B0082"
    property color textColor_tsmo:"#f2feb4" // "#FFFF00"
    property color textColor_oth:"#ff9f9f" // "#D2691E"
    property color textColor_zon:"#e8ffae" // "#32CD32"
    property color textColor_iht: "#ffaef2" // "#7B68EE"
    property color textColor_fla: "#ffb7ae" // "#1E90FF"
    property color textColor_cau:"#aeb7ff" // "#800000"

    property color textColor_hovered:"#d8d8d8" // ""
}

property var scrollBar: QtObject {
    property color handler: "#6b6b6b"
}

property var annotations: QtObject {
    property bool bold: true
    property int fontSize: 9
}

property var button: QtObject {
    property int width: 29
    property int height: 29
}

property var menu: QtObject {
    property color bgColor: "#000000"
    property color bgColorHover: "#555555"
    property real bgOpacityHover: 0.6
    property real bgOpacityPress: 1.0
    property color textColor: "#ffffff"
    property real fontSize: 12.0
    property bool fontBold: true

}

property var panel: QtObject{
    property color bgColor: "#000000"
    property int width: 360
    property int width2: 200
}}
```

EDIT: if i include it in main.qml with

```
Globals {
    id: globals
}
```

This way all properties are easily accessable!

Comment: That's how many people do it :-) Here is a tutorial: http://imaginativethinking.ca/make-qml-component-singleton/

Comment: I found a solution i think its better :P

Comment: Using an `id` in `main` will have a lookup overhead, the deeper the object tree the more the overhead. Use a singleton.

Comment: A singleton is that much better then?

Comment: Yes, use a singleton, or put your values in a `.js` and import them locally.